# Linux command line instructions from python

Tags: python, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

Is there a method for issuing command line instructions directly from the python shell?

Comment: Check out these answers to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.system` -

```
import os
os.system('<command line instruction>')
```